# Extracting Certain numbers of Rows based on repeatation?

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, size, unique-constraint

I have a dataframe –mydata- including more than 2000 rows something like this:

```
Id  Name    Score
R1  sam       76
R1  Sosan     8
...      ...     ...
R4   jack     2
R4   Tom      76
R4   samy     8
R5   Check    9 
…     ...     ..
R6     Anderson   2
...       ...     ..
```

Now, I want to extract the Ids which are repeated more than a certain number, for example 4. I could extract the size of the unique numbers by group by and size like this :

```
Mydata.groupby(by=[‘Id’]).size()
```

But, I can not extract only the Ids based on the threshold.

Comment: Do you want the extract whole row for `Id`'s that have a count > n? or just the `Id`'s?

Comment: No just the Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `value_counts` which counts the occurrence of `Id` then, filter the result which is `Series` by the number of occurences:

```
num = 2
s = df['Id'].value_counts()
print(s[s>num].index.values)
```

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding`.